# Approver doesn't see Approval state items in Sitecore Workflow

Tags: sitecore, workflow, sitecore8

I want to test out the Sample Workflow in Sitecore 8. This is what I have done so far:

- Insert the sample workflow in the standard values of the template
- Created two test users: **Test Editor** and **Test Approver**
- Created two roles: **SubmitionRole** and **ApprovalRole**
- In Security Editor I assigned **Read**, **Write** access including the 3 workflow rights to the **Draft** state for the **SubmitionRole** role and assigned this role to **Test Editor**
- In Security Editor I assigned **Read**, **Write** access including the 3 workflow rights to **Awaiting Approval** and and **Approved** states for the **ApprovalRole** role and assigned this role to **Test Approver**

Then I created an item from that template with the **Test Editor** and the item went into the Draft state. So I submitted the item in the Workbox.

Now when I log in with the **Test Approver**, there's nothing in the Workbox. I can see the Workflow and its **Approval State** in the Workbox, but there's nothing inside it. As admin I can see the item waiting in the Approval state.

Here is a screenshot of the Access Viewer for the **Test Approver**:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do both users have read/write access to the item itself, i.e. under `/sitecore/content/home` ? What about languages under `/sitecore/system/Languages`, do they have `Language Read/Write` access set (you need to show these fields from using the "Columns" option)

Comment: After granting language read/write, the Approver can see the item in the Approval State. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your user/role has language read and write access to the relevant item languages located under `/sitecore/system/Language`. The `Language Read` and `Language Write` are a separate set of fields which you can expose in the Security Editor by selecting them from the "Columns" option. The content approval role needs both Language Read and Language Write on the relevant language items:

[image]

Comment: Granting rights to language read/write solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign `Write` access to the workflow state items (`Awaiting Approval` and `Approved`). This means that `ApprovalRole` is allowed to edit those items, not items in that state.

What you need to set is:

- **Workflow State Write** for the `Awaiting Approval` state (controls whether or not a user can update items which are currently associated with a specific workflow state)
- **Workflow Command Execute** for the commands below `Awaiting Approval` state which should be allowed for the role (controls whether or not a user is shown specific workflow  commands)
- **Write** access to the item itself (the one that was submitted from the Draft state to the Awaiting Approval state).

And that should be it.
.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As you can see in the screenshot those rights are already granted. Still nothing in the Approval state.

Comment: I don't see any screenshot showing **Write** access to the item which in in the workflow. Have you set this one?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I just checked and the roles have both write access to the items. Still nothing in Approval state.

Comment: I've tested this and it worked for me (**note**: Approver role was a member of Sitecore Author role).